# htaccess rule not working without R=301 flag?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, redirect

My quest to understand htaccess continues. I haven't read anything useful in the documentation for this problem. This is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# e.g. Rewrite 'contact' to 'index.php/main/lessons'
RewriteRule ^contact$ index.php/main/lessons
```

The rule does not work, it is as if the rewrite doesn't even take place. The url is unchanged as just get a blank page. I want to redirect any request to `/contact` to `/index.php/main/contact`. However, when I add the `[R=301]` flag, 
it works. I see the permanent redirect request in chrome developer tools and I end up at the right page. Any help?

Thanks.

This is what I get from my error log with `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3` in my `httpd.conf`:

```
[Sat Jan 24 21:50:29.243747 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5028:tid 908] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:61103] ::1 - - [mysite/sid#73702837d0]   [rid#73716b5310/initial] [perdir C:/Sites/mysite/] applying pattern '^contact$' to uri 'contact'
[Sat Jan 24 21:50:29.243747 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 5028:tid 908] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:61103] ::1 - - [mysite/sid#73702837d0]   [rid#73716b5310/initial] [perdir C:/Sites/mysite/] rewrite 'contact' -> 'index.php/main/lessons'
[Sat Jan 24 21:50:29.243747 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5028:tid 908] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:61103] ::1 - - [mysite/sid#73702837d0]       [rid#73716b5310/initial] [perdir C:/Sites/mysite/] add per-dir prefix: index.php/main/lessons -> C:/Sites/mysite/index.php/main/lessons
[Sat Jan 24 21:50:29.243747 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 5028:tid 908] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:61103] ::1 - - [mysite/sid#73702837d0][rid#73716b5310/initial] [perdir C:/Sites/mysite/] trying to replace prefix C:/Sites/mysite/ with /
[Sat Jan 24 21:50:29.243747 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 5028:tid 908] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:61103] ::1 - - [mysite/sid#73702837d0][rid#73716b5310/initial] [perdir C:/Sites/mysite/] internal redirect with /index.php/main/lessons [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Sat Jan 24 21:50:29.248751 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5028:tid 908] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:61103] ::1 - - [mysite/sid#73702837d0][rid#737168f168/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/Sites/mysite/] add path info postfix: C:/Sites/mysite/index.php -> C:/Sites/mysite/index.php/main/lessons
[Sat Jan 24 21:50:29.248751 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5028:tid 908] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:61103] ::1 - - [mysite/sid#73702837d0][rid#737168f168/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/Sites/mysite/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Sites/mysite/index.php/main/lessons -> index.php/main/lessons
[Sat Jan 24 21:50:29.248751 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5028:tid 908] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:61103] ::1 - - [mysite/sid#73702837d0][rid#737168f168/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/Sites/mysite/] applying pattern '^contact$' to uri 'index.php/main/lessons'
[Sat Jan 24 21:50:29.248751 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 5028:tid 908] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:61103] ::1 - - [mysite/sid#73702837d0][rid#737168f168/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/Sites/mysite/] pass through C:/Sites/mysite/index.php
[Sat Jan 24 21:50:29.249748 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5028:tid 908] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:61103] ::1 - - [mysite/sid#73702837d0][rid#73716af2e0/subreq] [perdir C:/Sites/mysite/] add path info postfix: C:/Sites/mysite/main -> C:/Sites/mysite/main/lessons
[Sat Jan 24 21:50:29.249748 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5028:tid 908] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:61103] ::1 - - [mysite/sid#73702837d0][rid#73716af2e0/subreq] [perdir C:/Sites/mysite/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Sites/mysite/main/lessons -> main/lessons
[Sat Jan 24 21:50:29.249748 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5028:tid 908] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:61103] ::1 - - [mysite/sid#73702837d0][rid#73716af2e0/subreq] [perdir C:/Sites/mysite/] applying pattern '^contact$' to uri 'main/lessons'
[Sat Jan 24 21:50:29.249748 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 5028:tid 908] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:61103] ::1 - - [mysite/sid#73702837d0][rid#73716af2e0/subreq] [perdir C:/Sites/mysite/] pass through     C:/Sites/mysite/main
```

I should also note that I am using CodeIgniter.

Comment: The URL (that you see in the browser address bar) is _supposed_ to stay “unchanged” if you only issue an internal rewrite, and not an external redirect. As to why you get a “blank page”, that could be due to any kind of error in your script.

Comment: Do you have any other rules? I would add the `[L]` flag. You might want to follow [the instructions on how to log/debug](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) to figure out what exactly Apache is doing. You are working with path-info, but I thought it was possible to internally rewrite with path info.

Comment: @CBroe I know that, but it does not explain why I am getting this behaviour.

Comment: @BelegNeurion: Can you show your full .htaccess in question

Comment: @anubhava That is my entire htaccess file at the moment. After coming across this problem I backed up my original and replaced it with the file in the description so I could narrow down the problem.

Comment: @Sumurai8 I added `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3` and have pasted my log in the description.

Comment: I am confused where the subrequest comes from. Up until the 4-but-last-line it looks pretty normal to me. What happens then is a mystery to me.

Comment: Okay, after testing this at home, the output is identical to the working version here. Could you make a dummy file test.php with something like `echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` and then modify this rule to instead point at that. If that works correctly, I assume it is something related to how codeigniter works, but I am not really familiar with that.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Ok, I created a file called `test.php` at the root with `echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` as its content. I changed the rule to `RewriteRule contact /test.php` and the page displays `/test.php`. So that rewrite works. It seems to be a problem with rewriting to another controller.

Answer (score 0):

Using code igniter you can just define redirections in "application/config/routes.php"

Just add this line:

```
$route['contact'] = 'main/contact';
```